# Configuring Oracle Apex on Amazon AWS ec2 and Oracle RDS

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, oracle-apex, oracle-ords

I am trying to configure Oracle Apex on Amazon AWS ec2 and using Oracle RDS as Database instance. I have registered as free user for learning purpose. This is the first time I am configuring ec2 + ORDS for oracle Apex.

While i am configuring ORDS for Oracle Apex (ec2) and hitting command: **java -jar ords.war**
It asks to "**Enter the username with SYSDBA privileges to verify the installation [SYS]:**" but I my user doesn't have SYS privileges and I am unable to grant SYS privileges to it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZs8s.jpg)

Could some help me out with this. I am stuck at this point and unable to start APEX due to this. 
I have attached the error

Comment: Did you go through Amazon's walkthrough for setting up Oracle Apex with RDS? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.Oracle.Options.html#Appendix.Oracle.Options.APEX

Comment: Jeff Kemp has also got some decent posts on the topic http://jeffkemponoracle.com/2011/09/08/installing-oracle-11gxe-on-amazon-elastic-cloud/

Comment: A word of warning for running Apex using RDS. Some of us have noticed that the developer toolbar of Apex does NOT show up when doing application development and probably related to this is the fact that you cannot save default named reports that you want accessible to all users using interactive reports. Apex will only save private reports for the user who produces that custom interactive report. This cripples app development in my opinion. You will be better off at this point, unless someone has a solution to this issue, to install the Database on EC2 as well as the ORDS app server.

Answer (score 0):

According to user MichaelB@AWS (Amazon staff account):

> For the issues with ORDS, you should skip (by entering "2") steps
>   involving the ORDS schema and PL/SQL gateway. The ORDS schema is not
>   required to support the APEX RESTful listener, and is not currently
>   supported on RDS Oracle. The specific options may vary between
>   versions of ORDS.
>   https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=711534

The APEX+APEX_DEV options do not create the correct ORDS users, in particular there's no ORDS_METADATA created which is where most of the important ORDS packages and data are stored.  Without SYSDBA (not available on RDS) you won't be able to install ORDS either.

From the documentation:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.Oracle.Options.html
the minimal ORDS.war configuration and associated schemas needed to get APEX working is available on Amazon's RDS as a replacement for the deprecated APEX Express Listener.  It isn't a complete install of ORDS for RESTful services.

The solutions are:

1. Wait for Amazon to support ORDS on RDS
2. Install Oracle yourself on an EC2 instance and forget RDS

Comment: Hi there, i am curious if you think there is a way of installing apex 5.1 and yet connecting to RDS (currently docs say apex 4.2)? Its annoying that its an older version.